# Creating or updating multiple mysql lines using Yii model

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, yii

I've recently started working with Yii, so forgive the ignorance :)

I have an SQL query which returns multiple rows (array of arrays), i then want to insert those rows to DB:

```
$queryResults = $command->queryAll();
$model=new Campaigns();
foreach ($queryResults as $CActive) {
    $model->setIsNewRecord(true);
    $model->attributes=$CActive;

if($model->save($CActive)) {
    echo "Good!";
}
```

the problem is even though i'm setting the model with new record it has a record of the previous PK (since it's the same model).

do i need to create a new model for each row? (doesnt seem likely...)

Thanks as always,
Danny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a new instance at every insert, like this, otherwise you are just updating one model over and over.

```
$queryResults = $command->queryAll();

foreach ($queryResults as $CActive) {
    $model=new Campaigns;  
    $model->attributes=$CActive;

    if($model->save($CActive))  echo "Good!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! that is what i thought... isnt this very resource consuming?

Comment: The instance creation isn't, but the inserts will definitely take their toll.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
 $queryResults = $command->queryAll();

         foreach ($queryResults as $CActive) {

            $model=new Campaigns;  

            $model->attributes=$CActive;

            if($model->save($CActive)) {
    echo "Good!";
}
```

Well you must need to create instance for every row..its Yii core requirement..
            }

Comment: This is what he originally had.

Comment: your answer is exactly like Örs', so either you add some valuable info(an alternate method maybe), or delete this answer.